# app-index.js:32 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. In Next.JS

Tags: next.js, error-handling, jsx, styled-components, semantic-ui

I use flowbite for accordion and this error occured:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "flex items-center justify-between w-full py-5 font-medium rtl:text-right border-b border-gray-200 gap-3 bg-white" Client: "flex items-center justify-between w-full py-5 font-medium rtl:text-right text-gray-500 border-b border-gray-200 gap-3"
```

I have no idea on what happened here.

I have tried out to add this in my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  compiler: {
    // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
    styledComponents: true
  }
};

  module.exports = nextConfig;
```

but the error message didn't disappear and when i click my accordion it didn't collapsed